# ExtJS 4 Combobox Vertical Scrollbar Is Gone!

Tags: extjs, combobox, scrollbar, store, extjs4

```
cmbCombobox.getStore().loadData(arrayData);
```

I use this code to load my arrayData into Combobox.
getStore() method does not exists anymore in ExtJs 4.
So i use this code to load data:

```
cmbProvince.store.loadData(provinceData);
```

But vertical scrollbar is gone when i load data by this code.
Has anyone realized this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing today. You should be able to do:

```
cmbProvince.createPicker()
```

to force it to "redraw" the dropdown, which added the scrollbar back.